# Help identifying pest on indoor palm

Tags: pests, pest-control

found these under the leaves of my indoor palm, not sure if these are two type of pests or young/mature of the same one. Both the long brown ones and the small dark ones easily scraped off). Thought it might be scale however it looks different from the types of scale I've encountered so far (I'm based in the UK, if that helps).
The palm leaves have been turning yellow lately (no stickiness or sap though), I suspect it might be due to the pest? Suggestions welcome. Pics below. Thanks!
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I think the brown ones, if easily scratched off, are scale. The small black ones are hard to ID from these images. Try to get as much as possible off the plant, maybe even with a wet cloth (with diluted dish washing soap). There are many strategies to get rid of these insects, however from experience I haven't found the best one yet. Try to find some on internet, one that seems okay for you to use.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah my guess would be scale too, I think the small dark ones are too. ON IT!